# Update individual form element values in database via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have quite a few input elements on a page that a user can change.  I don't want to submit a form.  I just want the database value to be changed after the user changes the value inside one of the elements.

I'm currently experimenting with binding focusout to each of the inputs.  Is this the way it's usually done (facebook, etc..)?

```
    $('input').focusout(function() {
    var current_val = $(this).val();
    var preset_val = $(this).attr('rel');//attribute set with original value
    if (current_val !== preset_val) {
                alert ('Value changed.');//where I would post to php page to update database
            }
    });"
```

Comment: There's the `[on]change` event, give it a try (test with all browsers!)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, are you looking for code review? The subject of how data-binding works and javascript data-binding techniques is very broad. Check AngularJS, Knockout.js and Ember, these 3 are big libraries that implement this sort of thing

Comment: Yes, I do this myself, and i use this way too! I bind the `blur` event on all `input:text` and i call my Ajax function if the current value is different than the original one : `$(this).attr('defaultValue') != $(this).val()`

Comment: Use onChange or blur(and compare manually) and you got to use AJAX if you don't need to submit your form

Comment: @Benjamin No, just wanting to know if focusout is going to assure that the data gets updated.  If there's a better way then I want to do that.  For example, in the example above does an item get updated if the user closes the page, hits the back/forward button.  Is onchange a better option??

Comment: There is no way to save correctly data when the user close the window.

Comment: @JoDev `onbeforeunload` says differently.

Comment: @Chris ok, i confess ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is "usually done" is to wait until the user clicks a button to save or commit the changes. If you're going to update each change, you should make sure to be very clear about that to the user.

The appropriate event to use will be dictated by how aggressive you want to be in capturing changes. For per-keystroke updates, `keyup` would be appropriate for inputs, `click` for selects and radios/checkboxes. Less aggressive would be `blur` or `change`.

One way to be extremely proactive about capturing any possible change is to attach a `click` and a `keyup` to the form element itself. This will also save the overhead of adding a listener to every element. Each time an event is fired on the form, you can either a) check the original target, or b) ajax the entire form, or c) loop all the elements and detect changes, only ajax changed fields.

`onbeforeupload` can be used to do a final check of the form in case the window is closed, as well, but that's probably being a little too hyper.

**Documentation**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLFormElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onkeyup
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onblur
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick

Comment: The `click` event is *never* appropriate for `<select>` elements, radio buttons or checkboxes. It doesn't react to the user making changes via the keyboard, and there's no reason not to use `change` for them - there's no difference in when the events are fired, unlike with text inputs.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist As I said, it depends on how aggressive you want to be. There's no reason not to use the click event if you want to be hyperactive in detecting any activity on a form. Indeed, one could apply a click and keyup event to the form itself and AJAX every field, if you wanted to be a total spaz.

Comment: Thanks.  I just see a lot of sites doing this without defining the process to the user.  It's pretty common now.

Comment: Very thorough answer Chris.